# SQL Server : join 2 tables yielding required output

Tags: sql-server, join

I am trying to join 2 tables `TBL_A` and `TBL_B` to get the desired output with color filter.

It is working perfectly when the filtered `Color` is present in `TBL_B`.

But it doesn't return the required output when the filtered color value is not in `TBL_B`

Here is the code I am using at the moment:

```
DECLARE 
    @START_DATE DATETIME,
    @END_DATE DATETIME, 
    @COLOR VARCHAR(10)

SET @START_DATE = '2021-12-07' 
SET @END_DATE = '2021-12-08' 
SET @COLOR = 'Red'  -- can be Blue or Green based on requirement

SELECT      TBL_A.ID_CLM,
            TBL_A.DAY_CLM,
            TBL_A.DT_CLM,   
            TBL_B.CLR_CLM
FROM        TBL_A
LEFT JOIN   TBL_B 
ON          TBL_B.DT_CLM = TBL_A.DT_CLM
WHERE       TBL_A.DT_CLM BETWEEN @START_DATE AND @END_DATE 
            AND
            (TBL_B.CLR_CLM IS NULL OR TBL_B.CLR_CLM IS NOT NULL)
```

Graphical representation of what I actually need:

[Image with different outputs and required one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBLTq.png)

Comment: Can you please edit your post and include sample data and desired ouput as text instead of image?

Comment: Please avoid posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are cancelling your OUTER join by thea fact that you filter on B table...
Just remove the filter a set it into the join predicate like this :

```
SELECT      ...
FROM        TBL_A
            LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL_B 
                 ON TBL_B.DT_CLM = TBL_A.DT_CLM
                    AND (TBL_B.CLR_CLM IS NULL OR TBL_B.CLR_CLM IS NOT NULL)
WHERE       TBL_A.DT_CLM BETWEEN @START_DATE AND @END_DATE
```

Comment: You're Genius and straight to the point. Thanks a million.  Just a minor tweak was required to full fill it Instead of "TBL_B.CLR_CLM IS NULL OR TBL_B.CLR_CLM IS NOT NULL" it goes as "TBL_B.CLR_CLM = @COLOR". I have upvote and also marked it as answer as it directs me to correct path :)